# Ethernet Shield not connecting

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, web-server, ethernet-shield

I've mounted an Ethernet Shield on top of an Arduino UNO. The Arduino is connected via usb to my pc and to the network via ethernet through a switch.
I'm running a simplified verison of the WebServer example and the function to Ethernet.begin() always returns EthernetNoHardware.

I've tried different setups changing the ethernet cables and connecting directly to the router. I also tried adding specific ip, gateway and subnet parameters to Ethernet.begin() however the output doesn't change and the server can't be reached:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0F, 0xCC, 0x1E }; //mac address on the sticker
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 134);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
IPAddress DNSserver(192,168,1,1);
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Ethernet.init(10);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);

  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield not found.");
  }


  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}
```

output:

```
Ethernet shield not found.
server is at 192.168.1.134
```

Any idea on what the issue might be?

Comment: I'm using a W5100

Answer (score 1):

In your sketch DNS IP parameter is missing in `Ethernet.begin`.

It should be `Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dns, gateway, subnet);`